# Replacing negative id's with correct positive Ids?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `items` and `items_archive`.  Both have identical columns, and the only rows you need to worry about are they both have an id row and a timestamp row which is going to be used to help order and replace the id's.

Here's the problem, I recently restored a bunch of new rows to `items_archive` from old text data.  This old text data did NOT have the original id's, so I started just counting negatively so as to not affect the existing id's in either table.  However, not upon inspection I can see that things actually line up quite perfectly and I want to replace the negative id's with their proper ones.

Here is what my current query and data looks like -

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT idx,t_stamp, 'items' as src FROM items
UNION
SELECT idx,t_stamp, 'archive' as src FROM items_archive
) as t
ORDER BY t.t_stamp DESC;
```

yields a table like this

```
id         t_stamp          src
==================================
1878    2018-09-08 09:54:40 pallets
1877    2018-09-08 09:02:58 pallets
1876    2018-09-07 16:07:45 pallets
-808    2018-09-06 09:53:39 archive
-801    2018-09-05 13:43:52 archive
1873    2018-09-05 13:00:32 archive
-800    2018-09-05 11:48:55 archive
1871    2018-09-05 11:05:13 archive
```

It's obvious that -808 should be 1875, -801 should be 1874, and -800 should be 1872.  How can I achieve that at a mass scale?

I was thinking maybe making another temporary table that has all the id's from min to max, along with the timestamps in order based on the table I just showed you.  Then I could join on the time stamps and the simply update the rows in my archive table.  I am able to make the temporary table with the t_stamps, but I am at a loss of how to order the id's now in the new column from max to min, in order of the timestamp.  How can I do that?

Or, if there's another way you can think of, please let me know.  My extensive manual observation of this tiny table (~2k rows) shows that the negatives fit into place perfectly.

Using MySQL 5.6.

Comment: Why would you need to do that? `id`s are not supposed to carry any meaning, including ordering.

Comment: Trust me, I tried explaining this to my senior coworker.  There's heirarchy invovled with another table referencing these id's with more restored data, but I made it such that the relationship exists.  I personally don't see what the issue with the negative id's is, but until I'm the supervisor this is my job.

Comment: "It's obvious that -808 should be 1875, -801 should be 1874, and -800 should be 1872. "  Not to me.

Comment: This is off a production line.  Everything is made in order so the time stamp is literally the order the products where made.  So if 11:48:55 was the 1871 item made, and the next time stamp is a negative id, that was actually the 1872nd item made.

Again I believe this is all pointless anyways but it's what I'm told to do.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, make a temporary table with timestamp and add an ordering / index column e.g.

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (Order by t_stamp) as myrank
```

then you can link to that table to do the update.